# Using partially applied functions, performance issue

Tags: scala

```
object E7 {
  def next_prime(primes: List[Int]) = primes match {
    case ps@(h :: t) => {


      // Version 1
      val rpq = ps.reverse.exists _

      // Version 2
      val rpq = ps.reverse.exists(_)


      (Iterator.from(h + 1).find((v) => ! rpq(v % _ == 0)): @unchecked) match {
        case Some(v) => v :: ps
      }
    }
    case Nil    => List(2)
  }

  val primes = Iterator.iterate(List[Int]())(next_prime)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(primes.drop(20001).next.head)
  }
}
```

First version takes 3.6s to complete, second - 19.3s! What's the difference?

Edit: Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_21)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is interpreted as

```
{ val temp = ps.reverse; (x: Int) => temp.exists(x) }
```

while the second one is interpreted as

```
(x: Int) => ps.reverse.exists(x)
```

This explains the difference: you have to reverse each time in the second case, but only once in the first.  I am not sure where in the spec it says that this is what you get in each case (or if it does).